# Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class TextView in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I made a layout for my app and it works perfectly on Nougat and up, but for whatever reasons app crashes on Android 6.0 with following error:

```
05-01 18:26:02.658   805  1839 I ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.vanced.manager/.ui.MainActivity} from uid 10081 on display 0
05-01 18:26:02.691 13123 13123 I art     : Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
05-01 18:26:02.692 13123 13123 I art     : Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
05-01 18:26:02.699   805  1623 D ConnectivityService: notifyType CAP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 100]
05-01 18:26:02.825  9919  9987 I FontsContentProvider: Received query name=Exo&weight=600, URI content://com.google.android.gms.fonts
05-01 18:26:02.825  9919  9987 I FontsContentProvider: Query [name=Exo&weight=600] resolved to {Exo, wdth 100.0, wght 600, ital 0.0, bestEffort false}
05-01 18:26:02.829 13123 13123 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.vanced.manager, PID: 13123
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime: Theme: themes:{}
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vanced.manager/com.vanced.manager.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class TextView
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class TextView
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.vanced.manager.ui.fragments.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:32)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1188)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1238)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 9 more
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class TextView
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(L
05-01 18:26:02.839   805  2693 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.vanced.manager/.ui.MainActivity
```

Error happens in this layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/eightdp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="?colorSurfaceVariant"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:contentPaddingRight="8dp"
    app:contentPaddingLeft="8dp"
    app:contentPaddingTop="5dp"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vanced_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vanced"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo_bold"
            android:text="@string/vanced"
            android:textColor="?colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and problem is with `<TextView/>` tag. I'm unsure why does this happen on Marshmallow and not on Nougat+ (haven't tested lollipop but I think problem occurs there too). Can anyone explain?

**UPDATE:** Here's `HomeFragment.kt`

```
package com.vanced.manager.ui.fragments
import android.content.Context
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.Networkimport android.net.NetworkCapabilities
import android.net.NetworkRequestimport android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*import android.view.animation.Animation
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator
import com.vanced.manager.R
import com.vanced.manager.adapter.SectionPageAdapter
import com.vanced.manager.core.fragments.Home 

class HomeFragment : Home() { 
    private lateinit var sectionPageAdapter: SectionPageAdapter
    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2

    override fun onCreateView( 
        inflater: LayoutInflater, 
        container: ViewGroup?, 
        savedInstanceState: Bundle? ): 
    View? { 
        activity?.title = getString(R.string.title_home) 
        setHasOptionsMenu(true) return  
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false) }
```

Comment: `Binary XML file line #20` which in line no 20?

Comment: I included the layout xml code where the error happens.

Comment: i know. but what is line no 20 in xml?

Comment: Line 20 is where TextView tag starts

Comment: Commenting out didn't solve the problem, same error occurs

Comment: show your `HomeFragment` please.

Comment: Updated question to include HomeFragment

Comment: did you call  `vanced_title`  in this fragment?

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean with declaring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 05-01 18:26:02.833 13123 13123 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error
>   inflating class TextView

**android:textColor="?colorPrimary"** invoke  **`<attr format="color" name="colorPrimary"/>`**. It will be good approach if you use

```
 android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"  // call hex code from color xml
```

**NOTE**

Seems like your  **`android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vanced"`** causing issue. Kindly remove and run.

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Comment: Thanks guys I'll try that

Comment: @Xinto remove `app:cardBackgroundColor="?colorSurfaceVariant"`

Comment: Removing app:cardBackgroundColor didn't solve the issue either

Comment: @Xinto For test case, Remove TextView and run.

Comment: Sorry for not responding, gradle build takes a bit long for me, will reply in about 5 mins

Comment: Removing textview solved the problem, what could it be? Is there an issue with drawable start or what? I'm pretty sure it's not textColor because I have other textview using same exact  textColor

Comment: @Xinto `android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vanced"` is vector image?

Comment: Yes but I have another textview using a vector drawable too, perhaps it's too heavy?

Comment: @Xinto Sorry, comment your `android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vanced"` and run.

Comment: Using srcCompat doesn't display logo at all, I guess I'll have to move logo out of textview

Comment: @Xinto you can do that

Comment: Haha, yeah... I always hated pre android N version except KitKat, now I have even more reasons to do that xD

Comment: @Xinto Well. But here your device android 6

Comment: I'm using emulator and only found out issue when my friend reported crash on my discord server, I'll update question with correct answer. Thanks for helping me out! Cheers

Comment: Need vector drawble permission ?

Comment: Don't think so because other vector drawables work just fine, checked gradle build file too and I did specify use of vector drawables

Answer (score 0):

In the textview property

remove

```
 android:textColor="?colorPrimary"
```

Add

```
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
```

Comment: Well, I have colorPrimary as attribute because I have 2 themes that need separate colors for colorPrimary and I want to change that text depending on theme, is that the only variant?

Comment: that case you should apply theme in the activity tag in the manifest